# importing csv data in python

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, csv

I have a csv file with around 130 columns and 6000 rows

what is the best way to import them into python, so that I can later use them in a classification algorithm(columns are the labels and rows are individual samples)

Comment: Use one of the import functions? Your computer should be able to handle that.

Comment: See also: [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41585078/562769)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.read_csv('foo.csv')
```

Pandas identify the headers automatically and is a great tool for data wrangling. 
[10 Minutes intro to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)

Answer (score 13):

For small data, I think [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) is the way to go.

For "medium" data, I recommend [dask.read_csv](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html)

And for big data, I recommend [spark.read.csv](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader)

Comment: Agreed. On my laptop (8G ram, i5 processor), reading in CSV's up to around 1GB isn't much of a problem using pandas.read_csv. Keep in mind also that read_csv has the handy feature of being able to read gzipped CSV's.

Comment: So do the other two!

Answer (score 0):

You can also SFrame. First [install graph lab](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create.html). Then:

```
import graphlab as gl
data = gl.SFrame.read_csv('data.csv')
```

If you're 'hardcore' you can use [python's basic csv reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), but then you will have to write loops to manage the data yourself, so why bother reinvent the wheel, just use pandas or Frame.

Comment: what's better? pandas or SFrame?

Comment: SFrame is technically better, but it's use is restricted and limited documentation. Pandas is free and has more community support.